# JSLint: SyntaxError: invalid quantifier {

Tags: javascript, jslint

on this line of code:

```
var regex = /{{([^}]+?)}}/g;
// ----------^
```

JSLint show an error:

> SyntaxError: invalid quantifier {

the regex works

```js
var regex = /{{([^}]+?)}}/g;
var string = "bla bla bla {{ findme }} bla bla bla";
console.log(regex.exec(string));
```

how fix JSLint?

Comment: `how fix JSLint?` Use a better Linting like ESLint, or escape the `{`  `/\{\{([^}]+?\}\}/g`

Comment: escape fix the problem.